# Replacing outdoor light fitting

Tags: electrical, wiring, lighting

My home in Western Australia was built 4 years ago. I want to replace the basic outdoor light rose with a new LED bunker wall light. But the terminals on the light fittings are different.

The basic rose has 4 terminals but the new bunker has only 3. There are 2 wall cables connected to the old light - one has 3 wires (red, black, green/yellow). The other has 2 wires (red, white). The old rose has a terminal just for the white wire but the new bunker does not. So what shall I do with the white wire?

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. Pictures of the old and new fixtures' terminal blocks would really help us help you. And, you should probably [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know how best to participate here.

Comment: What are the wire colors at the switch?